# I can't import external project

Tags: maven, kotlin, maven-3

I have Maven project:

```
d:\dev\proj1
```

also I have another Kotlin project

```
d:\dev\proj2
```

In **IntelIJ IDEA 2018.3** I add to prj1 new proj2 as module.

```
Project Structures -> Modules
```

In `d\dev\proj1\pom.xml` I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>prj1</groupId>
    <artifactId>prj1</artifactId>
    <name>PRJ1</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>prj2</module>
    </modules>
```

But

```
<module>mixed-pojo</module>
```

has red color and as result in `prj1` in **Main.java**

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import prj2.Mixed // error here
```

Not compile. I get error:

```
Unresolved references prj2
```

I need to import project `prj2` to `prj1`.
How I can do this in Maven?

Comment: If you have pom file which contains modules it can't be packaging `war`.... it must be `pom` instead.

Comment: OK. But how import external project and build this two projects by maven?

Comment: What kind of external project?

Comment: prj2 - is a Kotlin Gradle project.

Comment: Than why are you using a Maven parent with a module which is Gradle based? If you like to use it as a dependency than you are going the wrong way..

Comment: So do you mean, that I need to build prj2 on Maven and them can use it (e.g. jar) in prj1 ? Is I'm right?

Comment: Yes you are correct.